# Same web property ID is tracked twice

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using the following code in my page, in order to have Google Analytics and Tag Manager.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r;i[r] = i[r] || function() {(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();a = s.createElement(o),m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)})(window, document, "script", "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "ga");

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx', 'auto');
    ga("require", "displayfeatures");
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

and

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx"></script>
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxx');
</script>
```

So I'm getting warning "Same web property ID is tracked twice" in Google Tag Assistant.

Is there anyway I can fix this warning?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have two Google Analytics codes on your page and both are sending 'pageview' hits to Google Analytics. The first one is somewhat older `analytics.js` snippet and the second is a little bit newer `gtag.js` snippet. None of them has anything to do with Google Tag Manager.

Consider using just **one**, either `analytics.js` or `gtag.js`. Note that if you'll also install GTM and set up pageview tracking in GTM you'll get the same issue again because GTM will duplicate the existing analytics snippet functionality.